# Auto renewal Subscription based In App purchase Windows phone 8.0

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, in-app-purchase, subscription

I am developing an app that implements In app purchase it's working fine,I want to implement auto renewal subscription based IAP means suppose any user purchase space on my own server to put data and after one month user need to again pay for space,I want that would auto renewal without any interruption of user,basically I want to implement subscription based In app purchase is it possible in Windows phone 8.0

Answer (score 2):

The In App Purchase model does not support this type of transaction. There is nothing stopping you from implementing billing clients every month via your own servers.

If you do not want to get in the business of billing (I know I wouldn't), I would recommend using the consumable in app purchase. You could store the purchase date on the phone or preferably on a server that the user subscribed for the next month. Each time the user opens the app you check your service if the subscription is still good based on device or user ID. If it is time to renew, you prompt the user to pay for another month.

Comment: What if the user delete the app? Then the info stored on the app will be lost.

Comment: Ya ok I Got it we can stored the info on server also

Comment: arent all receipts of a user stored by Win App Store? grab them from there